# jProfiler. Not working after temporary connection error

Tags: jvm, profiling, jprofiler

I run JVM with option

```
-agentpath:/home/adeptius/.jprofiler10/agent/10204_10.1.2/jprofiler10/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=7001,nowait
```

It works and GUI from Windows connecting succesfully. 
But if my computer go to hibernate mode or happen temporary disconnect - jProfiler will not be able to connect second time (GUI endlessly trying to connect). On remote machine log:

```
JProfiler> Reconnection.
JProfiler> Using sampling (5 ms)
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
```

There is only one way to make jProfiler working again - restart webApp.
upd: If connect and disconnect right way (from exit button in GUI) - all ok.

Comment: Do you have any output in $TMP/jprofiler_error.log?

Comment: jprofiler_error.log - no such file on whole file system..

Comment: I could find it in tmp folder: `/tmp/jprofiler_error.log`

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and found a solution with the `ss` command. Do like:

```
$ netstat -an|grep 8849
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8849            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:8849      xxx.yyy.zzz.xxx:49572   ESTABLISHED
```

Then:

```
ss -K dst xxx.yyy.zzz.xxx
```

with the IP you got from the netstat command. You can probably specify the port also, but this kills all connections from the foreign address.

After that I was able to connect with JProfiler again.

Comment: thank you! modified command: `sudo ss -K dst \`netstat -an|grep 8849 | awk {'print $5'} | cut -d ':' -f1\``